# How to use gdb to debug into a C program's corresponding disassembly?

Tags: c, debugging, gdb, disassembly

Using VC can bring up disassembly window and travel across it. But using gdb seems not so direct:

E.g. I've got a myadd.c

```
void main(){
   int i=0;
   int j=i+1;
   j+=2;
}
```

> gcc -g myadd.c
>
> gdb a.out
>
> b 2 //set break point at int j=1+1;

Now I can use "disassemble" command to see disassembly code. My requirement is to debug "into" this disassembly code like VC could. I tried 's' command, it directly goes into next "C" statement, not disassembly statement.

How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To jump to the next assembly instruction, use `stepi` (short `si`) instead.

See [this](ftp://ftp.gnu.org/pub/old-gnu/Manuals/gdb/html_node/gdb_37.html) for more information, especially how to use `display/i` to show the next machine instruction.

Answer (score 1):

For a reasonably nice assembly view, use `la p` (`layout prev`) and step with `si` (`stepi`). Use `C-x a` to return to/from regular gdb prompt. In some cases, other layouts may be useful as well.